# How is zonal flow defined and computed?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, statistical-mechanics, flow, turbulence, non-equilibrium

The transition to turbulence in pipe flow was recently observed to be in the same universality class as directed percolation. This was done by reinterpreting the turbulence and laminar flow in terms of predator-prey dynamics. See e.g. [this](http://arxiv.org/abs/1505.02807) paper.

A third element was added to the predator-prey dynamics: the zonal flow. This is a particular fluid configuration that has the ability to re-laminarise the flow. It eats up the turbulence. The elements of the predator-prey model are related to fluid dynamics by
\begin{align}
& \text{nutrient} && \leftrightarrow && \text{laminar flow} \\
& \text{preys} && \leftrightarrow && \text{turbulent flow} \\
& \text{predators} && \leftrightarrow && \text{zonal flow}
\end{align}

My question is the following: how is the zonal flow defined precisely? I get a feeling for what it is and what it does, but the fact that there is a plot of a definite flow configuration [here](http://arxiv.org/abs/1505.02807) suggests that the zonal flow can be defined in a precise way and even computed. How?

Comment: According to the abstract:  "Here we report numerical simulations of transitional pipe flow...", to which my immediate visceral response was "I never trust numerical simulations that I didn't screw up myself!". This feeling only got stronger when I looked at their simulation methodology, which I would characterize as completely insufficient for my taste, even though they claim that it is state of the art.

Comment: @CuriousOne - That is slightly pessimistic don't you think? With that attitude you can immediately dismiss any research done by others, numerical or experimental. Experiments are similarly possible to 'screw' up. Maybe you can clarify why their methodology is flawed according to you? While I don't have the time to go through the paper in detail, it looks like an interesting approach to understanding turbulence and while i can't interpret the results at the moment the authors seem to know what they are talking about.

Comment: I am not dismissing all research, I am dismissing simulations as a tool to replace experiments. A simulation is always GIGO. It's perfectly OK to use it for technical purposes or to compare against real data, but a simulation of pipe flow doesn't replace pipe flow for the purposes of physics, which are different from the purposes of e.g. aerospace engineering. The description of the methodology is in the Appendix. IMHO the sampling is too sparse. I understand why they can't make it any better, but that's no excuse.

Comment: Thanks for you interest guys. This does not help to anwser my question though.